# How do I install ubuntu studio and remove dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, software-installation, uninstall

I have dual boot with ubuntu mate 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver) and windows 10. I want to install ubuntu studio and remove ubuntu mate and windows 10. I don't want more dual boot. How do I do this? Do I need to remove Grub to? Am I overcomplicating this, and what I need is just a normal install of ubuntu studio?

Comment: You have several options: An advanced user would use Gparted to eliminate the Windows partition, and juggle packages to replace Mate with Studio. A beginning user would simply download an Ubuntu Studio installer and let it wipe the entire disk. Both methods require a complete backup of all your data - repartitioning by either method risks data loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The simple way to do this
- Backup your data!
- Create a bootable media with Ubuntu Studio.
- Verify the media.
- Boot from media (into Ubuntu Studio)
- Delete every partition on the disk you're installing on
- Install Ubuntu Studio